# C++ help on sort within STL program

Tags: c++, stl

So I have tried all types of combinations,  but I want to sort the titles of a vector and I can not get to them  My question is how do I get the sort to work with the title?

```
  class Seminar

    public:

        Seminar(int number = 0, string date = "yyyy-mm-dd" , string title = "")
        {
          Number = number;
          Date = date;
          Title = title;
        }

        int get_number() const {return Number; }
        string get_date() const {return Date; }
        string get_title() const {return Title; }

    private:
        int Number;     // Seminar number
        string Date;      // Date of Seminar
        string Title;   // Title of Seminar
}
```

To make the long story short the program will read a file and push the information into the vector.  For example:

```
    Seminar s(integers, calendar, line);

            All.push_back(s);






vector<Seminar> All;

vector<Seminar>::iterator it;


    if(Letter == "F" || Letter == "f")
      {
        sort(All.begin(), All.end(), ?? );
        for(it = All.begin(); it != All.end(); it++)
            {

                cout << it->get_title() << endl;
            }

      }
```

Comment: You should learn about constructor initializer lists.

Answer (score 2):

One simple way is to implement `operator<()` for your `Seminar` class; then the default `sort` algorithm will use it and do the right thing, something like this should work:

```
bool operator<(const Seminar &s1, const Seminar &s2) {
    return s1.get_title() < s2.get_title();
}
```

Comment: thanks, I had used got it literally a minute before you replied

Comment: Cool, you could still press "Accept"!

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following is one way to do it. You'll have to use `Sortfunc` as a sort function predicate.

```
class Sortfunc : public std::binary_function<Seminar, Seminar, bool>
{

public:  

  bool operator()(Seminar lhs, Seminar rhs)
    {
      // use '<' to sort ascending 
      // use '>' to sort descending
      return lhs.get_title() < rhs.get_title();
    }
};
```